# How to add thumbnail of Base64 image in Selenium Extent report

Tags: c#, html, selenium, base64, extentreports

I been using the base64 image for screenshots to be attached in my HTML extent report.

The code i been using is given below.

```
Screenshot file = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
string image = file.AsBase64EncodedString;

exTest.Fail(msg, MediaEntityBuilder.CreateScreenCaptureFromBase64String(image).Build());
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("FAIL >>>>  " + msg);
```

This is giving an extent report with relative path to my screenshot image as below.[Which is my expectation]

[Extent report with Base64 image button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWRLy.jpg)

Here instead of image, A Base 64 button is showing. I need to see a thumbnail of image instead of that button and still the image should be Base64 (Not related to HTML file).
Please help me to achieve this.

Edit: I am using extent report C# v3.1.3

Answer (score 1):

you have to do this by yourself. here's how I do it using jsoup:

```java
public static void addThumbnailToScreenshot(String filePath) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        Document report = Jsoup.parse(file, "UTF-8");
        Elements elements = report.select("a[data-featherlight='image']");
        for (Element element : elements) {
            if (element.attr("href").startsWith("data:image/png;base64")) {
                String thumbnail = String.format("<img class='r-img' src='%s'>", element.attr("href"));
                element.select("span").remove();
                element.append(thumbnail);
            }
        }
        BufferedWriter htmlWriter =
                new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filePath), "UTF-8"));
        htmlWriter.write(report.outerHtml());
        htmlWriter.close();
    }
```